# $f_n=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ uniformly converges to 1

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

This is the problem that I am trying to prove. Show that $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ where $x\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ is uniformly convergent to $f(x)=1$. It will be great if someone can tell me how to prove this.

Comment: Seems you need a condition on the domain of $f_n$, since $\lim_{x\to 0}f_n(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Because of the above comment, it seems unlikely that the convergence you seek will be *uniform* for x ∈ (0, 1/2).

Comment: It would be great if the OP wrote in his post what he tried in order to solve his exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think this is *wrong* to say the convergence on $x\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ is uniform. (You should carefully read again what Dan commented)  , since,  for any fixed $n$,
$$\sup_{x\in(0,\frac{1}{2})}|f_n(x)-1|=\sup_{x\in(0,\frac{1}{2})} (\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x}}-1)=+\infty$$,
which does not converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Do not answer very low-quality questions.